# Win 8.1 WDS deployment - Computer DNS Name Incorrect after image process

Tags: windows, deployment, wds

I imaged a computer using WDS services.  We have created an ImageUnattend file to answer all the necessary info.

The Image process finishes, the computer has joined our domain "KATYISD.ORG".
I can find the computer by its name "TEST321" in AD.
The computer is under the correct OU >> KATYISD.ORG/Junior High/CJH/Computers/Classroom/TEST321

But the DNS NAME is not correct … TEST321.KATYISD.ORG

Its missing the campus INITIALS in the name.

It should reflect >>> TEST321.CJH.KATYISD.ORG

Would you happen to know what might be the cause of this?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

CJH would be need to be an AD child domain of the KATYISD.ORG domain and the computer in question would need to be a member of that child domain. If you don't have a CJH AD child domain then I wouldn't expect it to get that computer name. Why do you expect it to get that name?

Alternatively, you could manually change the primary DNS suffix of the computer to CJH.KATYISD.ORG (which would create a DNS subdomain named CJH in the KATYISD.ORG parent DNS zone), but it doesn't sound like you're doing that.